# Google Distance Matrix API returning CORS blockade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, frontend

I've created a small ReactJS frontend app to create a table of origins and destinations, calculate the distances between them and outputting those distances in the table.

Everything should work fine, except that I'm getting a Cors policy blockade every time I try to generate the table. This is the function I've made for the Google Distance Matrix API:

```
export const getKm = (origins, destinations) => {

  var distance = require('google-distance-matrix');

  distance.key('HERE_IS_MY_API_KEY');
  distance.units('metric');

  distance.matrix(origins, destinations, function (err, distances) {
          if (distances.rows[0].elements.status == 'OK') {
            console.log(distances)
            return distances.rows.elements.distance.value;
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
      })
    }
```

These are the errors I'm getting from the console:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OB2V.png)

I've tried to google the problem, but I'm not able to find anything useful.

Do you guys maybe know in which direction I have to look for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows that you are calling the Distance Matrix API via webservice request.This webservice request that looks like this: *(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json? . . .)* should be used in the server side however you are using it in client side that's why you are running to a CORS error. Instead of using this webservice request, you can use the [Maps JavaScript API's Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) for client side usage of Distance Matrix.

Here is a snippet on how I use Distance Matrix service in my reactjs code:

```
    var orig = this.state.input;
    var dest = this.state.destination;

    service.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [orig],
          destinations: [dest],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, (response, status) => {
          if (status !== 'OK') { 
            alert('Error was: ' + status);
          } else {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

            //Loop through the elements row to get the value of duration and distance
            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
              var results = response.rows[i].elements;
              for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
              var element = results[j];
              var distanceString = element.distance.text;
              var durationString = element.duration.text;


              this.setState ({
                distance: parseInt(distanceString, 10)
                });
              console.log(this.state.distance);
              this.setState ({
                duration: parseInt(durationString, 10)
                });
                console.log(this.state.duration);
               }
             }
          }
          });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please also show your imports to give a better idea what modules you have used